# Unable to set 100hz refresh rate on a ultrawide gaming monitor

Tags: 20.04, display, intel-graphics, settings, framerate

I am trying to set the refresh rate of my monitor (Xiaomi Mi Curved Gaming Monitor. 3440 x 1440 native resolution) to 100 Hz on Ubuntu 20.04. As shown on [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfgsB.png), the option appears in the dropdown menu in the settings window. However, when I try to choose 100 Hz and press "Apply", the monitor does not even blink, and the last active option (60 Hz) becomes selected with a standard popup to revert or keep current settings. I am connecting the monitor using an HDMI 2.0 cable (cable was tested with another laptop, and it does support native resolution at 100 hz) to HP Elitebook 850 (i7 1185g7 with Iris Xe graphics and 2.0b HDMI port). I am not using any hubs.

How can I run the monitor with 100 hz?

**EDIT:**

The output of `xrandr -q`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.93 +  39.98  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
   3440x1440     50.00 +  99.99    60.00* 
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1720x1440     60.00  
   1920x1080    120.00   119.88    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, HDMI 2.0b port can transfer max. 4K at 60 Hz. You have to connect via Thunderbolt ➣ DP 1.2+ ➣ Monitor, then you can do 4K@120Hz or 8K@60Hz.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, my monitor is not 4k (it is 2k ultrawide, which implies far less pixels), and the system should support running at 100Hz (which is available as the option in the menu as shown on the screenshot). I do not have to connect via TB.

Comment: Does it accept `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --refresh 100` ? Well, if your monitor is on HDMI-0... I read it sometimes doesn't accept decimal numbers.

Comment: Nope, it does not, unfortunately. The command runs (I am on HDMI-1), but nothing happens (the monitor does not even blink). The refresh rate is still 60 Hz.

Comment: What does `xrandr -q` say?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, edited the post to include the command result

Comment: Are you really sure your graphics adapter is supporting your desired settings? Are you using your notebook with plugged in power cable? Have you set up full performance mode in battery settings?

Comment: @paladin, the laptop is constantly plugged in. Also, I have researched the specifications of Intel Iris XE [on the official site](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/208664/intel-core-i71185g7-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz-with-ipu.html), and according to what it says, it should support the maximum resolution of my display at 100Hz over the HDMI 2.0b port that I have.

Comment: Are you using an HDMI cable which is capable of those settings too? Is this cable specified for the settings you desire?

Comment: How much are 3440 x 1440 x 100 (HDMI-1) + 1920 x 1080 x 60 (eDP-1) = ?

Comment: @paladin, I tested the same setup (cable + monitor) using another laptop (macbook air), and it was able to run at exactly 100 Hz maximum (at native resolution)

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, I am not sure, but I deliberately turned off the screen of the laptop. In the display settings, I opted for single-display setup, with the only display used being my 34 inch monitor. So, no additional utilization of gpu capabilities here (although the Iris Xe can definitely run both simultaneously).

Comment: So that the logical conclusion has to be the specs of the monitor are not really what they say. And it doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, the conclusion is that the problem is in Ubuntu (or drivers, in some ways). As I mentioned, I actually run 100HZ native resolution using another laptop (with the same cable and the same monitor). But thanks for the help any way!

Comment: Did you confirm the 100 Hz running display is actually at 100 FPS? not from a driver fake that info? You can test by using a slowmo camera or using a flicker method of higher shutter speed and comparing with factors of 1/100 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I bought an external hub that connected via thunderbolt inteface (usb-c), which internally supports DP 1.4. I am able to set 100Hz, and the difference is very noticeable. It seems that HP is probably lying about the HDMI2.0b support, and a cheap HDMI adapter installed in a midrange laptop.

For notice - nothing changed (monitor, hdmi-cable, etc.).

Thanks to all for the help!